# retrieve changed contents of a jtable contained in a jscrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a Jtabbedpane that holds a JscrollPane which in turn holds a Jtable.

I would like to access the dynamically changed contents of the JTable via the JScrollPane. I have tried the following but I am stuck up at this point.

```
JScrollPane c = (JScrollPane)MyTabbedPane.getSelectedComponent()
```

Now c, the scrollPane has the changed table.

I saw that c.getComponents is returning two viewports and two scrollbars but not the Jtable.

Please tell me how can I access the JTable that the JScrollPane holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,to get table in JScrollPane...

```
jScrollPane.getViewport().getComponents()
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 4):

```
JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();  
JTable table = (JTable)viewport.getView();
```